# How can I estimate the reach of my Facebook ad using the Reach Estimate API while specifying the budget

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to estimate the potential reach of my Facebook ad campaign using the Reach Estimate API, but I need to input the budget as a parameter. However, it seems the endpoint doesn't accept budget as a parameter. Can anyone advise on how to accurately estimate reach while specifying the budget

I attempted to use the Reach Estimate API endpoint with the specified URL, but encountered limitations as it doesn't accept budget as a parameter.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const params = {
  targeting_spec: {
  specifications here
  },
  optimization_goal: 'REACH', // Set the optimization goal
  currency: 'USD', 
  daily_budget : 5
  access_token: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' // Add your access token here
};

// Make a POST request to the Reach Estimate API endpoint

axios.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_{my ad acc}/reachestimate', params)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Estimated Reach:', response.data.users);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error.response.data.error);
  });
```